# Как безопасно передавать данные по сети?

Tags: c, сеть

У меня есть сервер и клиент написанные на си которые используют протокол tcp.

Вопрос: Как мне передавать эти данные через обыкновенные сокеты безопасно, чтобы клиент и сервер использовали асимметричное шифрование, может какой-то протокол поверх tcp впихнуть или все-таки вручную легче шифровать?

Comment: Конечно есть, SSL, он же TLS.

Comment: Вот, OpenSSL - https://github.com/openssl/openssl

Comment: @Egorithm , я слышал что его только в браузерах используют, не будет ли колхозом впиндюрить его в свою прогу?

Comment: Нет, я пользовася им через Boost, Asio+Beast

Comment: Была даже утилита, которая просто оборачивала ваше соединение в SSL, в программе даже ничего писать не надо было. Но лучше, конечно, интегрироваться с `libssl`.

Comment: @virgin его используют везде, в каждом приложении где надо просто защитить соединения

Comment: @0andriy, да ну нафиг этот libssl, непонятно и инфы мало

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для TLS можно поднять пару haproxy (tcp->tls и tls->tcp).

Соответственно TCP клиенты идут на localhost, и TCP серверa слушают на localhost-е

Минусы:

- возможна пара мс задержки
- если на localhost кто-то забрался ... (то у нас уже всё плохо)
- если клиент распространяется как инсталлятор, нужно уточнить возможность поставки/работы haproxy/stunnel для конкретной платформы

Плюсы:

- не надо разбираться, как работают разные библиотеки на множестве платформ при написании софта.
- не надо разбираться, как персобрать софт, который написал Вася 5 лет назад с новой версией библиотеки без дырок.
- можно поставить несколько серверов на разных платформах на одном внешнем адресе:порту -- SNI.
- можно поставить несколько инстансов сервера
- легко интегрировать сервер, который уже написан с TCP

клиент:

```
global
  tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
defaults
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout client  3d
  timeout server  3d
  mode tcp

listen listen_$name
  bind $bind
  server s_$name $gate_addr ssl verify none sni str("$name.$sni_postfix")
```

сервер:

```
...
frontend fe443
  bind :443 ssl crt-list /etc/letsencrypt/haproxy/list.txt
  use_backend be_$name if { ssl_fc_sni -m dom $name }

backend be_$name
  server s_$name $to
```

(`$x` заменяйте, сроки с ним можно размножать)

---

**Вниманее**, в примере сертификаты не проверяются: `server ... verify none`. Соответственно проверку серверного сертификата лучше включить.

Клиентов можно пускать по паролю, когда соединение уже зашифровано, чтобы не усложнять вопрос распространением клиентских сертификатов.

Comment: минусующим просьба раскрыть тему

Comment: Haproxy не починит клиент) там прийдется запускать stunnel (я поставил плюс)

Comment: Haproxy можно настроить, чтоб он слушал TCP и превращал в TLS. Я stunnel тоже использовал до haproxy. stunnel настроить легче, но haproxy работал чуть стабильней.

Comment: как хапрокси настроить на клиенте?

Comment: @eri, ... поищу в своих заметках

Comment: нашел, вырезал (после этого не запускал), добавил в ответ

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, основное предназначение haproxy ведь создание кластера для веб сайтов, не проще ли тогда воспользоваться stunnel ?

Comment: @virgin примерно одинаково; ест haproxy несколько МБ; возможно, haproxy работал чуть стабильней; на сервере всё равно он же был тогда

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, haproxy подходит же только для http сервера?

Comment: есть `mode tcp` и `mode http`, во втором случае он парсит http заголовки, и может принимать решение на их основе

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov, а можно ли использовать haproxy или stunnel если клиентов неопределенное количество(они скачивают мой клиент и запускают его). Это же нужно настраивать stunnel на каждом клиенте или можно сразу сделать пакет где все будет настроено?

Comment: Вероятно можно; добавил алерт в конец и соображения в минус